# Polymorphic Jackson deserialization to POJOs in multiple Maven projects

Tags: java, maven, jackson

I have a POJO hierarchy like so:

```
@JsonSubTypes({
  @Type(value = FileShareConnection.class, name = "FileShareConnection"),
  @Type(value = HadoopConnection.class, name = "HadoopConnection")
})
public abstract class Connection
public class FileShareConnection extends Connection
public class HadoopConnection extends Connection
```

I want to deserialize some JSON into it using Jackson.
The problem I face is that they are each inside a different Maven project (FileShare connection is inside a FileShare maven project, and Connection is inside an API maven project).

As a result, I have a circular dependency between Maven projects (the abstract class needs to know about the subtypes and the subtypes need to know about the abstract class).

Any idea how I could solve this issue?

Comment: I did not understand why the abstract class needs to know about your subtypes .. as far as I know maven does not allow circular dependencies.

Comment: Inside @Type there is value = FileShareConnection.class, this is the syntax of Jackson for polymorphic deserialization of Json into POJOs

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the compile-time dependency, you can use the [ObjectMapper#registerSubTypes](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#registerSubtypes(java.lang.Class...)) or [ObjectMapper#registerSubTypes](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#registerSubtypes(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.NamedType...)) to register subtype information at run time.

Example:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.instanceOf;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonTest2 {

    // Assuming this is in base Maven module
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "_type")
    public static abstract class Connection {
    }

    // Assuming this is in different Maven module
    @JsonTypeName("FileShareConnection")
    public static class FileShareConnection extends Connection {
    }

    // Assuming this is in different Maven module
    @JsonTypeName("HadoopConnection")
    public static class HadoopConnection extends Connection {
    }


   // Assuming both modules are available here.
   // or you need to load classes via reflection(or some library)
    @Test
    public void testUseCustomPolymorphicTypeNameInSerializationOption2() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        mapper.registerSubtypes(FileShareConnection.class, HadoopConnection.class);

        Connection fileShareConnection = new HadoopConnection();

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        mapper.writeValue(sw, fileShareConnection);

        Connection value = mapper.readValue(new StringReader(sw.toString()), Connection.class);

        assertThat(value, instanceOf(HadoopConnection.class));
    }
}
```